# edit string without changing nonalpha characters

Tags: c, string, command-line

I need to make a program that edits command line arguments like this:

1. moves the first letter of each word to the end of word, and makes it lowercase
2. checks if the original first was lower/upper and makes the new first the same
3. adds "o" to each word with length < 3 , and "an" to the others
4. each non isalpha char remains the same
5. a word is considered divided when there is a space or a nonisalpha char

I have some code but my problem is that I don't know how to keep the non isalpha characters on the string without modifying them. Here is the code:

```
/*Example:
 
I *REALLY* like Yale's course-selection procedures.

to

Ian *EALLYro* ikelo Aleyo'san ourseco-electionso rocedurespo.
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\nNot enough arguments! Press any key to exit.\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    // copies the arguments to a string
    char src[100] = {0};
    for(int i = 1; i <= argc-1; i++)
    {
        strcat(src, argv[i]);
        strcat(src, " ");
    }
    printf("\nInput is:\n%s\n", src);


    // divides the main string in substrings when there is a space
    int k = 0, j = 0, m = 0, pos[50];
    char ans[100][100] = {0};

    
    // saves the position of the nonalpha characters
    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(src); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(src[i]) == 0 && isspace(src[i]) == 0)
        {
            pos[m] = i;
            m++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(src); i++)
    {
        if(src[i] == ' ' || src[i] == '\0' || isalpha(src[i]) == 0)
        {
            ans[k][j] = '\0';
            k++;       //for next word
            j = 0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            ans[k][j] = src[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nOutput is: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        processword(ans[i]);   // edits the words
        printf("%s ", ans[i]);

    }


    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is how i would edit the words:

```
char* processword(char* word)
{
    if(strlen(word) == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char first = word[0];                   // saves first letter
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(word); i++) // moves everything back one space
    {
       word[i-1] = word[i];
    }

    word[strlen(word)] = tolower(first); // moves first to end

    if (isupper(first) > 0)             // checks if the original first was uppercase, to make the new first the same
    {
        word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
    }

    // ads the suffix
    if(strlen(word) <= 3)
    {
        strcat(word, "an");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(word, "o");
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: This is not the best way to do it, but this is the closest to what you did: use `ans` to store words (even indices) and non-words (odd indices), non-words being a succession of space or non-isalpha characters. In your last loop, call `processword` only when `i` is even.

Comment: For a [example], you should include the necessary `#include<`, and also explain what's the current behavior of the program.